# Any idea what this growth is on my dog's belly?

Tags: dogs, health, skin-condition, anatomy

My neutered male 6.5 year old GSD/Husky/Lab developed this growth on his belly a couple weeks ago. It doesn't seem to bother him much. Any clue what it is? One source suggested it could be a mast cell tumor.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a nipple in the photo. If you have concerns about your dog's health, you should ALWAYS consult with your vet. Strangers on the internet can't give you a diagnosis from one photo.

Comment: That was my initial thought too, but I couldn't find the matching one on the other side. Turns out it is indeed an infected nipple which is why I didn't see more of them when I looked. Thanks for the comment though

Comment: @JonahM What did the vet when you visit? Could be useful information for other users with the same issue! If possible, please add this information in an own answer or as comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, this is your dog's nipple; if you look close you will find more.

It is totally normal; all mammals have them (both genders). We have had this question here before for other animals.

Be aware of similar looking growths on your pet and contact your vet if you are not able to make a positive identification of what you see.

Nipples have different shapes and colors, even in the same breed of animals, and their numbers might vary even within the same group of babies.

Comment: Took him to the vet and it is indeed an infected nipple. I had previously looked for the matching one on the other side but NOT being infected and inflamed, I hadn't been able to find it. Thanks!